# My Validation message not working in Thymeleaf

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new at Java. Using Thymeleaf and Spring-Boot.  Trying to show validation message on wrong input.  "Phone" property must be between 7 to 11 character int. 
Validation message will be shown if rules are not followed. her is

the model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User  {
@Column(name="phone")
@Size(min=7 , max=11 , message="Invalid Number")
private int phone;
```

}

my controller

```
  @PostMapping( "/signup" )
  public String signupPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")  User user ,
          Model model , BindingResult thebindResult ) {

    if(thebindResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("invalidPhone" , true);
        return "signup";

    }
```

my view

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone" class="cols-sm-2 control- 
                label">Phone</label><span class="bg-danger pull-right"   
                th:if="${invalidPhone}" th:errors="{*'phone'}" >phone 
                Error</span>
              <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group" >
                        <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa 
                fa-phone fa" aria-hidden="false" ></i> </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                th:value="${user.phone}" id="phone" name="phone" 
                roleId="phone" 
                th:field="*{phone}"  placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" 
                required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div
```

The Error

```
     Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'phone' 
     available as request attribute
```

Comment: can you post your `form` tag on your HTML and your `@GetMapping` method?

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" th:action="@{/signup}">  this is my form tag and GetMapping method is                   @GetMapping( "/signup" )                                                                   
 public String signup( Model themodel) {                                            
 //make an Object from                                                                          
 User User user = new User();                                       themodel.addAttribute("user" , user);                                                   
 return "signup"; }  @bphilipnyc

Comment: Typo: `{*'phone'}` should be `*{phone}`.

Comment: it doesn`t work still hava the same error?

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Aug 08 14:51:56 EET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'phone'

Comment: the comment above is a new error

Comment: The latest error you posted is becuase you cannot use `@Size` on an `int` it expects a String or Collection type. A phone number is _not_ an integer so i'd recommend changing the type to String. If you want to keep it as an int, you can use `@DecimalMin` and `@DecimalMax` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change your span tag as below.

```
<span class="bg-danger pull-right" th:if="${invalidPhone}" th:errors="*{phone}">phone Error</span>
```

Comment: These forum posts will help you.  [forum.thymeleaf.org/…, [forum.thymeleaf.org/th-field-and-th-errors-td4030018.html]

Answer (score 0):

The error message of:

`Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'phone' available as request attribute.`

is basically indicating that Spring can't find a bean to which it should bind.  Your form is looking specifically for a bean name called `phone`.  In actuality, your bean is called `user`.

You can also add a validator for separation of concerns.  You will likely be doing a fair amount of validation:

```
@Autowired
public UserController(UserFormValidator userFormValidator) {

    this.userFormValidator = userFormValidator;
}

@GetMapping("/signup") 
public String signup(Model model) { 
   model.addAttribute("user" , new User());  //it is expecting a user bean
   return "signup"; 
}

@PostMapping("/signup")
public String signupPost(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Errors result) {

    userFormValidator.validate(bean, result);
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
       //maybe log it here
       return "signup";
    }
    //some other logic
}

private final UserFormValidator userFormValidator;
```

Then **you'll want to tell Spring to bind to the `user` bean using `th:object`.**  Note the **corrected syntax on `phone`:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${user}" method="post" th:action="@{/signup}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
        <span th:errorclass="someErrorClass" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('phone')}" th:errors="*{phone}">* Please check the Phone field.</span>
        <div class="cols-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="false" ></i> </span>
                <input type="tel" <!-- helpful for mobile -->
                       class="form-control"
                       id="phone"
                       name="phone"
                       th:field="*{phone}"
                       maxlength="255" <!--or whatever, prevents overflowing your DB column-->
                       required="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then you can create a validator to support the form validation:

```
   @Component
   @Slf4j
   public class UserFormValidator implements Validator {

       @Override
       public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

           return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
       }

       @Override
       public void validate(Object model, Errors errors) {

           if (!SomeUtil.isFormValidationEnabled()) {
               log.debug("Validation disabled.  Returning.");
               return;
           }

           User user = (user) model;

           if (SomeUtil.isMissing(user.getPhone())) {
               errors.rejectValue("phone",
                      "phone.isMissing",
                      "Please enter a valid phone number.");
           }
       }
   }
```

You can read over the Thymeleaf docs for more examples.  It'll give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping( "/signup" )
  public String signupPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")  User user ,
           BindingResult thebindResult, Model model ) {

    if(thebindResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("invalidPhone" , true);
        return "signup";

    }
```

Change the position of your BindingResult object, you must place the BindingResult immediately after the object you are validating with @Valid.

Answer (score 0):

**From Controller, edit as below.**

```
@PostMapping( "/signup" )
public String signupPost( @ModelAttribute @Valid User user ,BindingResult thebindResult, Model model) {
    if(thebindResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("invalidPhone" , true);
        return "signup";
    }
 }
```

**From View Edit**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="phone" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
  <span class="bg-danger pull-right" th:if="${invalidPhone}">phone Error</span>
  <div class="cols-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group" >
      <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-phone fa" aria-hidden="false" ></i> </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{phone}" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" required="required"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

**Note**
Make sure your @GetMapping() Controller display Signup, u are passing User to Model
ie.

**@GetMapping Controller**
........

```
model.addAttribute("userModel", new User());

........
```

**Inform**

```
<form method="post" action="" th:object="${userModel}">
  //signup input...
</form>
```